# Alternative to VBA in a banking environment

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, language

I work in daughter company of a bank where our "in house developed IT system" is being written in VBA - years ago, the bank simply imposed restrictions on us regarding what language we can or cannot use.

Lately, the amount of business that we do has grown and some daily automated tasks already take approx. 6 hours, even though some of the time-consuming operations are being done in C++ through a DLL. Eventually, we will get to a point where the daily tasks will take more than 24 hours, at which point it will become a nonsense.

Hence, the question is, what can we do to speed things up. I was thinking along the lines of changing the language. What I would like is the possibility to

1. profile our code (very limited in VBA)
2. faster than VBA (i.e. compiled)
3. possibility to have interop between the language and Excel
4. possibility to call functions stored in DLL from the language
5. people in the bank only know VBA, hence the closer the language to VBA the better (i.e. rewriting everything in Qt/C++ is not a solution)

I thought of VSTO, but some posts on SO seem rather discouraging. What options do we have? Currently, we have approx. 50K lines of code, so its not a couple of excel files.

Any help is much appreciated, Daniel

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic - this is beyond the scope of this Q&A site. I'd really suggest getting with your parent company on a better solution - probably an ERP or at least some sort of database.

Comment: The parent company people are risk managers who know a little VBA and Excel, they are not the people to come up with a solution to this problem.

Comment: The parent company is the one who administers IT for you? There's a reason you're restricted, right? Otherwise you'd have your own IT dept that would help you with a solution. Let's also consider regulations in your industry and/or country(ies) regarding the type of information you handle. A small error can cost a lot in terms of time, customers, penalties and PR. If you are the one responsible for this decision, I'd look at hiring a consultant with expertise in the area.

Comment: The parent company administers our IT in terms of providing servers for apps that we bought from other SW companies, etc. From my points of view, even pushing the IT to get us a database server would be something close to impossible. Me and my risk colleague are the developers. The reason we are restricted is that few people can program in the bank, it has nothing to do with regulation  (how much safer is VBA than something else). So the question really is what I wrote it like - what is close to VBA but considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

This question probably belongs on stackoverflow rather than superuser.

However, pending a move ...

The most logical step would be the use of Visual Basic in a Visual Studio environment. This gives you full access to the Office development stack, provides easy(ish) development of Excel addins and would give you something of a migration path from current VBA code.

VB used to be very similar to VBA though these days it has morphed into something rather different since it is a first class member of the .NET languages. However, it still retains some of its roots and so some familiarity.

This will also open the possibility of engaging new developers who's skills may lie in more common languages such as C# for future developments.

The use of Excel applications remains remarkably common in banking and finance and this is a common solution to the problem.

Perhaps I should have also mentioned some possible alternative approaches. Excel files can be access from other languages though realistically, only the raw data not any embedded logic. Both PHP and Node.JS for example have libraries available for processing spreadsheets and I've used these in the past to do server based processing of spreadsheets before passing on to humans for use. I suspect however that this may not be that useful in this situation.

Perhaps the real answer is to bite the bullet and start to rework the spreadsheets into a more suitable environment. You can start by migrating the data in a SQL database linked back to the processing spreadsheets. Then begin to migrate the business logic to server processes either directly within the SQL server or in business logic applications running at the back-end.

Comment: SiddhartRout told me to move the question from SO to SU:)

Comment: Hmm, oh well. To be honest, any answer will be part opinion. My answer is based on experience in the UK finance and banking sectors.

Comment: The problem with the C# approach is that its an entirely new language, the banking people will not even consider this a possibility. Server-side calculations is even more in the impossible territory.

Comment: Agreed that C# seems like a big step which is why I recommend VB first. Once you are in that space, VS and .NET give you options for using other .NET languages should you get in external help. You might want to be a bit bullish with your management though since they are in danger of ruining their business by sticking their heads in the sand over the issue. Raise it as a risk and try to estimate some financial costs for not doing anything now, that may get them to take note.

Comment: People in SO often have no idea what's on topic elsewhere.

Comment: I have VBA → VB.NET transitioning experience and I generally recommend it for people familiar with VBA. VB.NET retains much of a VBA syntax while it unleashes enormouse power of .net. Also I think C# and VB are one of most feature-complete languages available. And they are similar at 98% so in future you might be able to hire skilled .net developers (those not religiously locked with C#). Although VB.NET differs from VBA and you will really need *a lot* of learning, start should be relatively acceptable. And most answers answered here on [so] for C# also apply to VBA, just convert the syntax.

Comment: Thank you all for answers, banking people surprised me hugely, they are willing to go for C# immediately.